# How to accept return values from lambda expression in C# multi threading program

Tags: c#, lambda, return

How do I use return value from a parameterized function that is passed as argument to a thread in C#?
The following code didn't work. Any simpler alternatives?

```
                namespace Param_thread
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static int largest(int x,int y)
                    {
                        if (x > y)
                            return x;
                        else 
                            return y;
                    }

                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        int result;
                        Thread finder = new Thread(()=> (result=largest(4, 5)));
                        finder.Start();
                        Console.WriteLine(result + " is greater");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Task`, specifically `Task.Run`.  It is specifically designed to represent the computation of a value in another thread, rather than the execution of a `void` method in another thread.  It will also appropriately handle all synchronization between threads when dealing with that result.

As for why your code doesn't work, the thread won't necessarily have computed the result by the time you go to print it out.  For the program to reliably work you'd need to have waited for the thread to finish, in addition to synchronizing the memory shared between the threads correctly.  Starting a new thread only to immediately wait for it to finish of course is rather pointless; you might as well just compute the value in the original thread.

Comment: For example: `result = Task.Run(() => largest(4, 5)).Result`. Note that if you use `finder.Join()` after the `finder.Start()` statement, that will solve the problem too. No explicit synchronization is needed, because calling `finder.Join()` implicitly provides the necessary synchronization to ensure the variable is up-to-date.